# How to clear data from all files present in a directory?

Tags: files, io

I have a folder which has some text files and other folders in it which in turn have more text files in them. I need a command which will recursively loop over the folder and clear all the contents from all the files present in that directory and its subdirectories.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `find`:

```
cd top_level_dir
find . -type f -exec bash -c "echo -n '' > {}" \;
```

For every filename it invokes Bash (not very efficient) and echos, without newline because of the `-n`, essentially nothing to the file, thereby overwriting its contents and creating a zero length file.

If you have a lot of files and/or have to this often a small (C/Python/Perl/Ruby) utility that reads from input a list of NUL terminated filenames and writes zero bytes to each of them would spead things up considerably ( `find -type f -print0 | your_zeroing_util` )

You can e.g. use the following as `your_zeroing_util`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

inp = sys.stdin.read()
while inp:
   if '\0' in inp:
      file_name, inp = inp.split('\0', 1)
      # print("emptying [{}]".format(file_name))
      with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
         pass
   inp += sys.stdin.read()
```

Comment: `wipe` (packaged for debian at least, or available from http://lambda-diode.com/software/wipe) is also good if you need to securely erase the files so they can't be recovered.  Note that copy-on-write (COW) filesystems like `btrfs` or `zfs` (or `qcow2` disk image files used by VMs) make it extremely difficult to securely erase files.